# how to extract the best population from different arrays?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, dataframe, statistics

I have a 8-10 sample arrays.

```
[W, T, I, Z, F]
[a, F, k, D, P]
[A, B, C, D, E]
[W, F, T, P, I]
[W, T, I, Z, F]
[H, c, B, V, C]
...
...
```

Each array has a unique value.

```
[0.4729,
0.7075,
0.8611,
0.8512,
0.4769,
0.3074
...
...]
```

I want to select best population.This population should include 5 different values. Any idea?

Note:If results are near to 1 , this means this population is better.

Thanks,